# PHP contact form continues to return error even though information is provided

Tags: php

I am working on a contact form but every time I try actually running it on my website I keep getting the error message "error with sending email". I'm not trying to do anything complex. I just want it to send the forms to my email. Thank you for helping. Also sorry about any bad formatting as this is my first stack overflow post.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $name = $_POST['Name'];
        $email = $_POST['Email'];
        $subject = $_POST['Subject'];
        $query = $_POST['Message'];
        $email_from = $name.'<'.$email.'>';

        $to="email@website.com";
        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "From: ".$email_from."\r\n";
        $message="   
             Name:
             $name     
             <br>
             Email:
             $email        
             <br>
             Subject:
             $subject
             <br>
             Message:
             $query
        ";

        if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
            header("Location:https://website.com/messagesuccess");

        exit();
    }
    else {
        echo "error with sending email";
        exit();
    }
?>
```

HTML:

```
<div style="margin-top:48px">
    <form action="action.php" target="_blank" method="POST">
      <p><input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Name" required name="Name" id="Name"></p>
      <p><input class="w3-input w3-border" type="email" placeholder="Email" required name="Email" id="Email"></p>
      <p><input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Subject" required name="Subject" id="Subject"></p>
      <p><input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Message" required name="Message" id="Message"></p>
      <p>
        <button class="w3-button w3-black" type="submit">
          <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i> Send Message
        </button>
      </p>
    </form>
</div>
```

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I keep getting the php error message yet all the fields seem to be in place? What am I missing?? Also huge apology since this is my first ever stackoverlfow post and I am a total PHP and stack overflow question asking noob.

Comment: Whose server are you using?  Are you using like a GoDaddy server?  You can't necessarily send e-mails from someone else's server.

Comment: I am hosting my website through inmotion hosting servers. I have had a php contact form work before. I can’t figure out why this one isnt.